# Solving a symmetric minimization problem with linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

[image]

I attempted this problem by using Lagrange multiplier, and it turned out easy to prove that $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=-\frac{1}{n}$ will minimize for $n\geq1$. However, this is a problem from a class dedicated to linear algebra, so I am wondering how would someone use concepts in linear algebra to get a same answer?

Comment: The equation describes a hyperplane.  The shortest vector will be the orthogonal projection of the origin on the hyperplane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1 = \big \vert -1 \big \vert  = \big \vert \mathbf 1^T \mathbf x \big \vert \leq \big \Vert \mathbf 1 \big \Vert_2 \big \Vert \mathbf x\big \Vert_2 = \sqrt{n}\big \Vert \mathbf x\big \Vert_2$
so
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \big \Vert \mathbf x\big \Vert_2$
with equality *iff* $\mathbf x \propto \mathbf 1$.  This is Cauchy-Schwarz, which people frequently first learn in a linear algebra class, so it seems like fair game for your linear algebra class.

Comment: Thank you, this concept is exactly what I am looking for and is covered in the lecture.